# Phonegap of cropping image for Android

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing on phonegap crop image using javascript or HTML. How to crop image after capture a photo or get the photo form library?

Comment: Welcome to SO, a place where we welcome questions to any programming related problems that you may have, however, we ask that you first show a genuine attempt towards the solution in which you seek as we will not just give out free code to those who do not try it first themselves. If you have code, please post it so you may be able to receive further assistance. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be cropping image  is possible via Android API. Phonegap only provides an interface to connect javascript to Android API.
or else you can use HTML5 canvas options.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/